# Htaccess rewrite rule not redirecting but works by attending desired url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am new to .htaccess and many websites have examples about when to use what, but none of them explain what part does what.

I have the following .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
# DirectoryIndex /$1 index.php?u$1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !marker  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} u=([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)  
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ %1? [R=301,L]   
RewriteRule ^/?([-a-zA-Z0-9_+]+)$ ?marker&u=$1 [L]
```

This is used for `index.php?u=$1` to `.com/$1` and it works when I navigate to `.com/$1` but when I navigate to `index.php?u=$1` it shows `index.php?u=$1`.

Question:

I want to redirect from `index.php?u=$1` to `.com/$1`.

I tried setting up `DirectoryIndex` but I got the error that my page is redirecting too many times.

Please help!

Comment: Try removing the first RewriteCondition .

Comment: Your first condition does not allow the old url and that is why the redirection from old url to the new one isnt happening.

Comment: @starkeen Or I am really stupid or output is same. I removed first 'RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !marker' and its same when I attend index.php?u=$1 it shows index.php?u=$1 and when I go to ./$1 it shows ./$1 so its same...

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: Just this as you see.... I am on localhost if that's important?